# CCC for SAP B1 : While synchronizing addon, Error : Parse ard file failed

Tags: sapb1

1. I have created light weight addon using Addon extension package.
2. And synchronizing addon.zip file on Cloud Control Center for SAP Business one extensions registry, while synchronizing addon it shows the error "Parse ard file failed".
3. I have question that "how to put successful addon for Cloud Control Center for SAP Business one extensions registry?"

** ARD File on Addon.zip**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AddOnRegData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" SlientInstallation="No" SlientUpgrade="No" Partnernmsp="VedhaSoft" SchemaVersion="3.0" Type="" MultipleVersion="false" OnDemand="" OnPremise="" ExtName="xxxxxx_210721_3" ExtVersion="21.7.21.3" Contdata="xxxxxx" Partner="xxxxxx" DBType="HANA" ClientType="W">
      <Validity>
        <SBOCompatibility>
          <Version From="" To="" />
        </SBOCompatibility>
      </Validity>
      <Configuration>
        <Repository>
          <Properties />
        </Repository>
        <Deployment>
          <Properties />
        </Deployment>
        <Assignment>
          <Properties />
        </Assignment>
      </Configuration>
      <Addons>
        <Addon Name="xxxxxx_210721_3" Group="" ForceFlag="" Visible="" AutoAssign="" SelfUpgrd="">
          <x86 AddonExe="" AddonSig="">
            <Installation>
              <Files />
            </Installation>
            <Uninstallation>
              <Files />
            </Uninstallation>
          </x86>
          <x64 AddonExe="QualityControl.exe" AddonSig="9D672BBF4C062056E404E07F8D770146" ExeDir="X64Client">
            <Installation>
              <Files>
                <File FileName="X64Client\Interop.SAPbobsCOM.dll">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
                <File FileName="X64Client\Interop.SAPbouiCOM.dll">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
                <File FileName="X64Client\QualityControl.b1s">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
                <File FileName="X64Client\QualityControl.exe">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
                <File FileName="X64Client\QualityControl.exe.config">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
                <File FileName="X64Client\QualityControl.pdb">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
                <File FileName="X64Client\QualityControl.vshost.exe">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
                <File FileName="X64Client\QualityControl.vshost.exe.config">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
                <File FileName="X64Client\QualityControl.xml">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
                <File FileName="X64Client\Sap.Data.Hana.v4.5.dll">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
                <File FileName="X64Client\SAPBusinessOneSDK.dll">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
                <File FileName="X64Client\XML\CFL_GRN_Inspection.xml">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
                <File FileName="X64Client\XML\GeneralSetting.xml">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
                <File FileName="X64Client\XML\Inspection.xml">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
                <File FileName="X64Client\XML\Menu.xml">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
                <File FileName="X64Client\XML\MenuRemove.xml">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
                <File FileName="X64Client\XML\QC1.bmp">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
                <File FileName="X64Client\XML\QC101.BMP">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
                <File FileName="X64Client\XML\Service.bmp">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
                <File FileName="X64Client\XML\wrench.bmp">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
              </Files>
            </Installation>
            <Uninstallation>
              <Files>
                <File FileName="X64Client\Interop.SAPbobsCOM.dll">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
                <File FileName="X64Client\Interop.SAPbouiCOM.dll">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
                <File FileName="X64Client\QualityControl.b1s">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
                <File FileName="X64Client\QualityControl.exe">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
                <File FileName="X64Client\QualityControl.exe.config">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
                <File FileName="X64Client\QualityControl.pdb">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
                <File FileName="X64Client\QualityControl.vshost.exe">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
                <File FileName="X64Client\QualityControl.vshost.exe.config">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
                <File FileName="X64Client\QualityControl.xml">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
                <File FileName="X64Client\Sap.Data.Hana.v4.5.dll">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
                <File FileName="X64Client\SAPBusinessOneSDK.dll">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
                <File FileName="X64Client\XML\CFL_GRN_Inspection.xml">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
                <File FileName="X64Client\XML\GeneralSetting.xml">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
                <File FileName="X64Client\XML\Inspection.xml">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
                <File FileName="X64Client\XML\Menu.xml">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
                <File FileName="X64Client\XML\MenuRemove.xml">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
                <File FileName="X64Client\XML\QC1.bmp">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
                <File FileName="X64Client\XML\QC101.BMP">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
                <File FileName="X64Client\XML\Service.bmp">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
                <File FileName="X64Client\XML\wrench.bmp">
                  <Actions />
                </File>
              </Files>
            </Uninstallation>
          </x64>
        </Addon>
      </Addons>
      <XApps>
        <XApp Name="" Path="" FileName="" />
      </XApps>
      <UDQs>
        <UDQ udqname="">
          <Hana FileName="" />
        </UDQ>
      </UDQs>
    </AddOnRegData>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Fill up the version in the From and To attributes of the section

```
<SBOCompatibility>
<Version From="" To="" />
</SBOCompatibility>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).